# jquery removing BR tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding two  tags dynamically when i click on remove button(just to make UI look better), I am not able to remove the space that those two BR's added. If i see in console, it is showing me as 
 (lower case), I have tried uppercase,lowercase . remove().

```
var container = $("#CCcontainer")
container.append("<div id =" + removeID + " ><div class =\"form-group col-sm-10\"></div><div class =\"form-group col-sm-2\"><button id=\"btn" + removeID + "\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-warning form-control\">Remove Card</button></div></div></BR></BR>");

//Below line is in a remove Card click action.

 $( "<br/>" ).remove();
```

Could someone help jhow to remove this space?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `br` selector for selecting all `<br/>` tag

```
 $("br").remove();
```

Comment: Sweet :). It worked but posed another problem that I did not expect. As it is removing all the BR's it is breaking my UI again. Is there anyway I can control only remove particular BR tag? I have a removeID unique value.

Comment: `$('#YourContainer').find('br').remove();` or you can use `$('br').eq(1).remove();` the  value inside `eq()` is the index , start from 0

Answer (score 13):

You can remove `<br>` using CSS or jquery.

CSS Code

```
#YourContainer br {
  display: none;
}
```

Or Using jQuery

```
$('br').remove();
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
  $("br").remove();
```

or more specific by target only `<br>` inside your `#CCcontainer` div if you don't want to remove all the `<br>` in the page like above code then:

```
$('#CCcontainer br').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

and you can also use hide function for remove  class='remove' tag 
for that only assign class  to br tag
and call this function as per your requirement $(".remove").hide();